# Azure AD to On-premise non AD Server

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

Can someone refer me to documentation on how to implement Azure AD on a Windows server 2016 that has no DC or on-premise AD, basically only one administrator profile on the server, and would like to replace that with Current Azure AD?

Or any recommendation on how to implement Azure AD to on-premise server that has no AD in place?
as well as push sql server authenication to use Azure AD.

Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to add the Windows Server 2016 to the Azure AD domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this as far as I'm aware without On-prem AD, is to add Azure AD DS to your azure ad in azure, then create a vpn to your premise. you can then use windows server to join that azure ad domain services. 
start here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/tutorial-create-instance

Because you cannot Azure AD Join a Windows Server without Azure AD DS, since azureAD is not full AD and does not provide the traditional services a AD Domain would.